# Is there a way to write a cookie using something similar to Document.cookie() in google apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script

So I have a Google Document with a script that saves the current name of the Google Doc in a cookie so the name is temporary. Then there is a button to change the name of the Google Doc. Is there a way to save the name of the Google Doc to a cookie? Do cookies even exist in Google Apps Script?

Comment: Show your code to let us know your query better.  Is this a server script or html script?

Comment: You should take a look at the [Properties Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/), it allows to store data for the script.